# Extjs 5 strange behavior of the getStore() method

Tags: javascript, extjs

I've faced with the strange getStore() method behavior.

Having main viewport with two regions: north and center. On the north region there is a button 'Show grid', if to click on this button QueryResultsGridView is loaded to the center region

```
var panelToAddName = Ext.create('MyApp.view.QueryResultsGridView', {});
var mainViewPort = Ext.getCmp('mainViewPort');
var centerRegion = mainViewPort.down('[region=center]');
centerRegion.removeAll();
centerRegion.add(panelToAddName);
```

my Store

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.QueryResultsGridStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'MyApp.model.QueryResultsGridModel',
    alias: 'store.queryResultsGrid',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'queryResultsGrid.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});
```

my ViewModel

```
Ext.define('MyApp.viewmodel.MainViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',

    requires: [
        'MyApp.store.QueryResultsGridStore'
    ],

    alias: 'viewmodel.main',

    stores: {
        queryResultsGrid: {
            type: 'queryResultsGrid'
        }
});
```

my Panel

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.QueryResultsGridView', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    requires: [
        'MyApp.controller.QueryResultsGridViewController'
    ],
    controller: 'queryResultsGrid',
    listeners: {
        afterrender: 'onFormAfterRender'
    },
    items:[{
        reference: 'queryResultsGrid',
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [
        {
            xtype: 'grid',
            reference: 'grid',
            bind: {
                store: '{queryResultsGrid}'
            },
            columns: [
                { text: 'Text1', dataIndex: 'text1', flex: 1 },
                { text: 'Text2', dataIndex: 'text2', flex: 3 }
            ]
        }]
    }]
});
```

my ViewController

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.QueryResultsGridViewController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',

    alias: 'controller.queryResultsGrid',

    onFormAfterRender: function(form, parent1) {
        console.log(form.down('grid'));
        console.log(form.down('grid').store);
    }
});
```

Now in console I see 2 Objects as suggested above. If I go inside the first Object there is a data inside it, but inside the second one store is empty. Could anyone suggest me why? Btw I need this store to run store.load().

first Object

[image: first Object]

second Object

[image: second object]

**UPDATED**

Here is https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/kf3/preview if it helps, you can see in the console 2 Objects I mentioned above. Source code is available here https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/kf3

Comment: does your grid have a `getStore()` method? like `form.down('grid').getStore()`

Comment: .getStore() has the same behavior as .store - nothing inside data

Comment: Here's another thing to consider trying: because you've defined the store on the view model, you should be able to get it directly from the there from the view controller. Try that as well, something like this.getView().getStore() from a VC handler, take a look at the VC docs for a full example then we can add a new answer.

Comment: yes, I've also tried it like that this.getViewModel().getStore('QueryResultsGridStore'); but still the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured it out. This problem is not occur if to set `afterrender` event for the grid (not for the panel itself) and use `this.getViewModel().getStore('queryResultsGrid')` as was suggested by Colin in the comments.

I've updated the Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Ext.getStore()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext-method-getStore) method to get any store

Comment: Ext.getStore('QueryResultsGridStore') returns undefined and
Ext.getStore() - same behavior as form.down('grid').store - nothing inside data

Comment: do you use sencha cmd? if so try specifying your store as your view dependency and building the app

Comment: Only stores registered with StoreManager can be retrieved by Ext.getStore(). Also every store with non-empty storeId config is automatically registered.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you have the store set to `autoLoad`? The store object changes from one moment to another and I wonder if due to `autoLoad` being set to true is causing data to be overwritten. Try removing `autoLoad` or setting it to false.

If this doesn't work, you could try setting up a [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/) so we can see this in action.

Comment: removing autoLoad doesn't help. The interesting thing is, getStore() method is working if I call it from actioncolumn grid handler (for a better understanding I didn't show it in my question). Anyway, I will try to show it with Sencha Fiddle.

Comment: I've created a fiddle, but I'm not sure how to run it, all the files are in a right place https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/kf3

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: I meant fixed the Fiddle, not the issue